# Protocol Buffer and WADL to JSON

Tags: javascript, .net, json, protocol-buffers, wadl

I've Protocol buffer (protoBuf) files which has models (c# class) and WADL files which has functionality for the WebAPIs controllers (controllers and methods in xml format). Now, I want to convert both (protobuf and wadl) it to Json standard format in 1 file. This json can be used by swaggerUI, SoapUI or any other tool which take json. And, when one modifies the Json in Swagger then it must also update corresponding protobuf and wadl.(I know it seems lot of work here, any easy way?) Can any one please let me know, How do I make it?

Comment: Found a resource to convert protobuf to json https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-buffers-schema, https://www.npmjs.com/package/proto2json, https://github.com/turn/shapeshifter

Comment: Using this link(https://github.com/devongovett/protobuf-jsonschema) will generate json schema from protobuf, most of the protobuf grammer is supported and rest you need to tweak the library, if required.